# How to replace Hadamard Product and Column wise addition with new Matrix operation?

Tags: signal-analysis, matrix

Let 
$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\\
    a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
 and 
$$
B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3}\\
    b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3}\\
    b_{3,1} & b_{3,2} & b_{3,3}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
and $C=A\circ B$, i.e.,

$$
C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1,1} \times b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\times b_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\times b_{1,3}\\
    a_{2,1}\times  b_{2,1} & a_{2,2}\times b_{2,2} & a_{2,3}\times b_{2,3}\\
    a_{3,1}\times  b_{3,1} & a_{3,2}\times b_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\times b_{3,3}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

and then I have to column-wise addition of $C$, i.e.,

$C'=[c_{1,1}+c_{2,1}+c_{3,1}, c_{1,2}+c_{2,2}+c_{3,2}, c_{1,3}+c_{2,3}+c_{3,3}]$.

My question is

Is there any other way to represent $C'$ in terms of column-wise addition of $A$ (i.e., $A'$) and column-wise addition of $B$ (i.e., $B'$)? or $A$ and $B'$?

Comment: Isn't $C^\prime$ just the _diagonal_ of $A^TB$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Exactly! Thanks a lot. That's what I wanted.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Can it be possible  to represent $C′$ in terms of column-wise addition of $A$ (i.e., $A′$) and column-wise addition of $B$ (i.e., $B′$)? or $A$ and $B′$?